# Networkmanager is populating resolv.conf with incorrect information and I can't override

Tags: arch-linux, dns, networkmanager, manjaro, resolv.conf

NetworkManager always sets my DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf to be 192.168.1.1 even though my router address is 192.168.18.1. Manually setting it to the latter works, but is overwritten constantly with wrong info. I can't tell where NetworkManager gets this incorrect info. This is true for both wired and wifi connections.

Some more info:
Connecting through wireguard works because resolvconf overwrites resolv.conf with a working nameserver (1.1.1.1)

Environment:
Manjaro Linux KDE default settings.

Comment: NetworkManager didn't invent this value. Couldn't it be that your router was 192.168.1.1, you changed its settings to 192.168.18.1 but forgot to change all of its DHCP server settings to match this? In such case the resolution is on the router, not on Linux.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that feedback. This seems likely to be the problem. I'm not sure where to set the DHCP server settings on my router, so I changed the router IP to 192.168.1.1 and that solved all my problems. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

it looks that it comes from you router. check /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient*/